# align this div at the top of the screen in the centre?

Tags: html, css

What I have at the moment is a div which contains a navigation bar, what I want is to have thie navigation bar me in the middle of the screen at te top; regardless of what resolution it is on?

**[HTML code](http://codepad.org/pFSQGIO9)**

```
<div class="navigation" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Homepage</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Products and Services</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[CSS code](http://codepad.org/YeHU2MZ0)**

```
body { 
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-image:url('/img/pattern.jpg');
}

#footer {
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0;
     width:100%;
     height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
     background:#6cf;
}

#header {
     background-image:url('/img/header_img.png');
     padding:10px;
     height:100px;
}


.navigation {
    background: url(images/navigation.png);
    height: 134px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    float: left;  
    width: 500px;
}
.navigation * {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navigation ul {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
    margin: 37px 0 0 20px;
}
.navigation ul li {
    background-color:White;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.navigation ul li a {
    background-image:url(img/navbutton_back.png);
    display: block;
    padding: 0 13px 0 0;
    color: #578ba0;
    text-decoration: none
}
.navigation ul li.selected a,
.navigation ul li.hover a {
    background-image:url(img/navbutton_back.png);
    color: #578ba0;
}

.navigation ul li a span {
    background-image:url(img/navbutton_back.png);
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 10px 10px 23px;
}
.navigation ul li.selected a span,
.navigation ul li.hover a span {
    background-image:url(img/navbutton_back.png);
}
```

Comment: Please, next time don't limit yourself in providing links only (what if the service is down?), but insert your source code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `float: left;` from your .navigation class and add `margin: 0 auto;` to it;

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh4qh/)

Comment: Yes thankyou this was the correct solution +1, plus why did someone thumb down my question? Did I not post something with it I should have

Comment: Maybe because firstly you didnt paste yout html and css here. And I recommend you to create jsfiddle for such questions, it will help community to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css attribute `margin:auto`

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rlcrews/z28V7/1/

Comment: Ok that works to an extent, but why when i change the size of the width, does it become un-centred?

Comment: Glad you got it working if you need to center the contents of the div depending upon the element you use you could use either 'left:50%' or 'text-align:center'